# Display Events from API in FSCalendar

Tags: ios, json, swift4, xcode9, fscalendar

This is my response from api

```
SUCCESS: { 
  "5": {
  "count": 1,
  "topEvent": false
  },
  "6": {
  "count": 1,
  "topEvent": false
  },
  "7": {
  "count": 3,
  "topEvent": true
  },
  "success": 1
}
```

In this response i have events in day 5,6 & 7, rest of the days there are no events.
Now, I would need to show the count in the center of calendar icon and it should be green when the topEvent is true.

what logic i apply in

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {

}
```

please help me..

Comment: first make sure that 5,6,7 must be date not a number.

Comment: i already used it basically it takes date parameter

Comment: these are 5, 6, 7 days of your current month? you need to form a Date with those days and compare with date provided by the delegate method

Comment: i can get current year and month from FSCalendar

Comment: URL: calendar/month/year
     where,
    month 1 - 12
    year in yyyy
    Method: GET
    As i will scroll calendar , it will fetch from server and make set there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have date parameter then To Set Events Base On Dates.
Instance of DateFormatter And Variables:

```
var datesWithEvent = ["2015-10-03", "2015-10-06", "2015-10-12", "2015-10-25"]

var datesWithMultipleEvents = ["2015-10-08", "2015-10-16", "2015-10-20", "2015-10-28"]

fileprivate lazy var dateFormatter2: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    return formatter
}()

func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {

    let dateString = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)

    if self.datesWithEvent.contains(dateString) {
        return 1
    }

    if self.datesWithMultipleEvents.contains(dateString) {
        return 3
    }

    return 0
}
```

for highlight Event

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, eventDefaultColorsFor date: Date) -> [UIColor]? {
        let key = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)
        if (self.remainderDates.contains(key)) {
            return [UIColor.red]
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: thanks and what about count? 
it should be center of calendar icon and it should be green when the topEvent is true.

Comment: Wait I will check

Comment: i also add the method of highlight color

Comment: okay now i'm understand the little bit logic..
now i want to call my api
URL: calendar/month/year where, month 1 - 12 year in yyyy Method: GET As i will scroll calendar , it will fetch from server and make set there.
when calendar scroll every time api will call..
can you tell me how can i do that?

Comment: Make a simple Array, hit the API and map all the date in Array then call this Array in CALENDERS  method